# Creating a function with two distinct horizontal asymptotes.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm creating content for a course, and I came across the following graph in the learning resource in the horizontal asymptotes section. I've been trying to replicate it using Geogebra, but I can't figure out how to create it exactly. Can anyone provide any insight as to how one would create such a function?

Thank you!

[image: Image of the function in question]